# Application Insight logs 403

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I use Application Insight to monitor a web API hosted as a PAAS service on  Azure. The resource is found at `api/v1/NameOfController`.

When I look at Failures in the in the portal (`Application Insights->Failures`), a lot of **403** errors are shown at the endpoint "GET/ :

[image]

**The detailed view in Analytics**

[image]

The API does not expose any services at the "root" - hence the 403 I guess. And as far as I can see, it's a bot calling from **0.0.0.0**?

Could anyone point me in some direction?

Comment: What is the Browser-Agent of these requests?

Comment: you are right about the 403 due to the services not exposing at the root level, but regarding the IP, it will always show as **0.0.0.0** by default as per [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status/2018/02/01/all-octets-of-ip-address-will-be-set-to-zero/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per @Jayendran said, the 403 error is due to the services not exposing at the root level.

For ip, due to EU General Data Protection Regulation, no client ip should be collected, see official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#client-ip-address-is-0000):
[image]